# How can I parse this JSON to get the rendered title?

Tags: json, swift

I used `json["title"]["rendered"].string!` to get the title but all I get is `nil`.

```
[  
   {  
      "title":{  
         "rendered":"Nachhilfe für mehrere Hauptfächer"
      },
      "comment_status":"open",
      "ping_status":"closed",
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON. You should post a valid JSON to with your question.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is missing some formating, but first it looks like the root element of the json is an array. You'll have to get that first element before you can access `title` then `rendered`.

Answer (score 0):

The top root is an array ( assuming it's swiftyJson ) you need

```
if let title = json.array.first?["title"]["rendered"].string { // json is JSON
  print("title is \(title)")
}
else {
   print("No title")
}
```